# Running command with NLTK Chat Reflections

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, chatbot

I'm making a chatbot assistant and I am trying to run a command when a specific word or scentence is entered.

In this example I wanted to make it so whenever I said "math" it would run the command "mathOperation"

Anyone know how to link the command to the chat?

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections

# this function the math i am trying to run
def mathOperation():
    print("Select an Operation")
    chat = Chat(pairs, reflections)
    chat.converse()


# this is the talking part
pairs = [
    ['my name is (.*)', ['hi %1']],
    ['(hi|hello|hey|hello|greetings|whats up)', ['Greetings Sir', 'Hello There', 'Welcome back Sir']],
    ['(.*)help(.*)', ['How may exactly I help you?', 'I can help you, Sir', 'What do you need help with?']],
    ['(.*)your name?', ['My name is TRAVIS', 'Call  me TRAVIS', 'Im TRAVIS, your personal assistant']],
    ['(.*)created you?', ['Dr. Teo Azevedo created me!']],
    ['(.*)how are you?', ['Im doing pretty good!', 'Im doing just fine, Thank you for asking!']],
    ['(.*)joke(.*)', ['Hear about the new restaurant called Karma? There’s no menu: You get what you deserve.']],
    ['(.*)robot?', ['Yes I am a robot, but I’m a good one. Let me prove it. How can I help you?']],
    ['(.*)thank you', ['Glad I could help!']],
    ['(.*)can you do?', ['I can: do Math, Browse, Play music, Communicate, and tell you the Time']],
    ['(.*)math', [' Setting up Calculator'], mathOperation()], # this is where im having a problem
    ['(exit|bye|quit)', ['It was great talking to you! See you Later']]
]

chat = Chat(pairs, reflections)
chat.converse()
```